# req.requestURI.substring in integer/phone to get the response

Tags: apex

The problem here is the Phone field/it is not a string field, it is throwing following error:

> invalid Illegal assignment from Integer to Case

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/CaseByPhone/*')
global with sharing class CaseByPhone{

    @HttpGet
    global static Case doGet() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        caseId= req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
          Case result = [SELECT COUNT() From Case  WHERE Asset.Phone= :caseId];
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: COUNT() in query returns an integer, if you want to retrieve an object query its desired fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COUNT()` query returns an integer so following query would fail:

```
Case objCase = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Case];
```

If you need to retrieve an object, query desired fields:

```
Case objCase = [SELECT Id, CaseNumber FROM Case LIMIT 1];
```

For your code to run you need to modify it to an return Integer:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/CaseByPhone/*')
global with sharing class CaseByPhone{

    @HttpGet
    global static Integer doGet() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        caseId= req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        Integer resultCount = [SELECT COUNT() From Case  WHERE Asset.Phone= :caseId];
        return resultCount;
    }

}
```

Note: Do not forget to add exception handling when you make a query or in general